# Jquery Find and Replace Number

Tags: jquery, replace, numbers, find

I am really struggling to find a solution to this i want to find every instance of a number in a paragraph of text.

```
<div id='text'>
this is the number 20px and this is the number 100 and this is the number 10.
</div>
```

So i want to take this and have it ouput the following. 20 100 10

```
<script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

        var text = $('.text').text().toString().search( new RegExp( /^[0-9]+$/ i ) );

        alert(text);    

        });                  
        </script>
```

from the alert i just want it to output the numbers in the text i.e 20 100 10, i now this is way off but any help to put me in the right direction i am banging my head against a wall, thanks.

Comment: Your pattern should be `/\d+?/`, can't think of the right funcs right now.

Comment: If there are negative numbers(-100) should you capture -100 or 100?

Comment: great point Mikael I modified my regexp for negative and decimal numbers too. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#text').html().match(/\-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g).join(' ')
```

creates a string with all numbers found inside the div element.

to get an array of all numbers found just remove the `.join()` method

Plase note that you have 'text' as id of your element, so you need refer to it as `$('#text')` and not as `$('.text')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you would replace anything, but to find all numbers, something like this is enough:

```
// results an array of numbers
var results = $('#text').text().match(/\d+/g);
```

Comment: Right, but won't match single digit numbers

Comment: Zlatev, + quantifier means 1 or more digits

Comment: `/\d+/.test("1")` returns true, because + means one or more digits

Answer (score 1):

If you use this:

```
var txt = $( '#text' ).html().match(/\d+/g)
```

it will give you an array of the numbers

Comment: Sorry, Harmen -- had this open and posted before I saw your response.